# Applying function decorators outside of decorator class' instantiating scope?

Tags: python, pipeline, python-decorators

I am attempting to modify the code base found at this [Github repository](https://github.com/vdymna/generic-python-pipeline). The project aims to create a system which uses function decorators to add functions to a directed acyclic graph representing a pipeline of tasks to perform on some given input.

I would like to modify the project by creating a `Task` class which has a method `process` that is decorated to perform the tasks in the pipeline opposed to the use of top level functions as is the currently functionality.

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    #@Pipeline.task()
    def process(self, input):
        return input

class AdditionTask(Task):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        super().__init__(self, name)
        self.value = value

    @Pipeline.task()
    def process(self, input):
        return map(lambda x: x + self.value, input)
```

I assume this is a valid decoration given the `example3.py` code provided in [this link](https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/python-class-decorators.html) describing Python decorators. Though it seems when attempting to do this an error is generated when supplying the decorator

> TypeError: task() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

As far as I can tell when the `AdditionTask` is instantiated, the function decorator is not within the same scope as the instantiation of the `Pipeline()` object. As evidenced by the example SSCCE below

```
from collections import deque

# https://github.com/vdymna/generic-python-pipeline/blob/master/pipeline/dag.py
class DAG:
    """Directed acyclic graph structure to manage pipeline task dependecies."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = {}

    def add(self, node, points_to=None):
        """Add new task not to the graph, specify optional 'points_to' parameter."""
        if node not in self.graph:
            self.graph[node] = []

        if points_to:
            if points_to not in self.graph:
                self.graph[points_to] = []
            self.graph[node].append(points_to)  # todo: need to make sure not to add duplicates

        # if sorted tasks and original graph lengths there must be a cycle
        if len(self.sort()) != len(self.graph):
            raise Exception('A cycle is detected in the graph')

    def sort(self):
        """Sort all the task nodes based on the dependencies."""
        self.in_degrees()

        nodes_to_visit = deque()
        for node, pointers in self.degrees.items():
            # find all root nodes
            if pointers == 0:
                nodes_to_visit.append(node)

        sorted_nodes = []

        while nodes_to_visit:
            node = nodes_to_visit.popleft()
            for pointer in self.graph[node]:
                self.degrees[pointer] -= 1
                if self.degrees[pointer] == 0:
                    nodes_to_visit.append(pointer)
            sorted_nodes.append(node)

        return sorted_nodes

    def in_degrees(self):
        """Determing number of in-coming edges for each task node."""
        self.degrees = {}

        for node in self.graph:
            if node not in self.degrees:
                self.degrees[node] = 0
            for pointed in self.graph[node]:
                if pointed not in self.degrees:
                    self.degrees[pointed] = 0
                self.degrees[pointed] += 1

# https://github.com/vdymna/generic-python-pipeline/blob/master/pipeline/pipeline.py
class Pipeline:
    """Create a pipeline by chaining multiple tasks and identifying dependencies."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = DAG()

    def task(self, depends_on=None):
        """Add new task to the pipeline and specify dependency task (optional)."""

        def inner(func):
            if depends_on:
                self.tasks.add(depends_on, func)
            else:
                self.tasks.add(func)
            return func

        return inner

    def run(self, *args):
        """Execute the pipeline and return each task results."""
        sorted_tasks = self.tasks.sort()
        completed = {}

        for task in sorted_tasks:
            for depend_on, nodes in self.tasks.graph.items():
                if task in nodes:
                    completed[task] = task(completed[depend_on])
            if task not in completed:
                if sorted_tasks.index(task) == 0:
                    completed[task] = task(*args)
                else:
                    completed[task] = task()

        return completed

class Task:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    #@Pipeline.task()
    def process(self, input):
        return input

class AdditionTask(Task):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        super().__init__(self, name)
        self.value = value

    @Pipeline.task()
    def process(self, input):
        return map(lambda x: x + self.value, input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pipeline = Pipeline()
    add_op = AdditionTask(4)
    print(pipeline.run(range(0, 4)))
```

---

**Is there a way I can decorate class functions with the function decorator defined in `Pipeline` to wrap class functions into the pipeline's functionality?**

---

The only potential solution I have now is to create a class global in `Pipeline`, that is, instead of defining `self.tasks` I would utilize `Pipeline.Tasks`, that way the addition of `Task`s to the pipeline is independent of scoping. But this has issues if I would like to create multiple `Pipeline`s and in the administration of the pipeline's tasks and DAG.

---

**EDIT:** Hmm, I think I want something akin to the final advanced decorator example [in this blog post](https://www.codementor.io/@sheena/advanced-use-python-decorators-class-function-du107nxsv). Here a decorator is created that is applied to a class. The decorator inspects the decorated class for attributes which it can then apply another decorator to. In this case, a decorator which determines a function's runtime. From the post,

```
def time_this(original_function):      
    print "decorating"                      
    def new_function(*args,**kwargs):
        print "starting timer"       
        import datetime                 
        before = datetime.datetime.now()                     
        x = original_function(*args,**kwargs)                
        after = datetime.datetime.now()                      
        print "Elapsed Time = {0}".format(after-before)      
        return x                                             
    return new_function  

def time_all_class_methods(Cls):
    class NewCls(object):
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            self.oInstance = Cls(*args,**kwargs)
        def __getattribute__(self,s):
            """
            this is called whenever any attribute of a NewCls object is accessed. This function first tries to 
            get the attribute off NewCls. If it fails then it tries to fetch the attribute from self.oInstance (an
            instance of the decorated class). If it manages to fetch the attribute from self.oInstance, and 
            the attribute is an instance method then `time_this` is applied.
            """
            try:    
                x = super(NewCls,self).__getattribute__(s)
            except AttributeError:      
                pass
            else:
                return x
            x = self.oInstance.__getattribute__(s)
            if type(x) == type(self.__init__): # it is an instance method
                return time_this(x)                 # this is equivalent of just decorating the method with time_this
            else:
                return x
    return NewCls

#now lets make a dummy class to test it out on:

@time_all_class_methods
class Foo(object):
    def a(self):
        print "entering a"
        import time
        time.sleep(3)
        print "exiting a"

oF = Foo()
oF.a()
```

Though this again still presents the same issue I identified in the original posting text, there is no way I see to pass a `Pipeline` instance to the decorator described by `time_all_class_methods`. While I may be able to decorate the `Task` class with a class akin to `time_all_class_methods`, it still would not be aware of an given instantiated instance of `Pipeline` to which the decorated attributes would be added; to `Pipeline.tasks`.

Comment: `Pipeline.task` is an unbound method (i.e., a regular function). You need some instance of `Pipeline` in order to call it.